# Classifications after better cluster found - Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I using kmeans to classificate data.

And I found my better k cluster with Elbow method and silhouette to validate decision.

So now how can i classificate my data and plot dist chart?

Could you please help me with this?

This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
%matplotlib inline

df_diabetes = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')


#Deletando a coluna "Classe"
df_noclass = df_diabetes.drop('Classe', axis=1)
df_noclass.head()


nomes = df_diabetes_noclass.columns
valores = df_diabetes_noclass.values
escala_min_max = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
valores_normalizados = escala_min_max.fit_transform(valores)
df_diabetes_normalizado = pd.DataFrame(valores_normalizados)
df_diabetes_normalizado.columns = nomes
df_diabetes_normalizado.head(5)


sse = {}
for k in range(1, 10):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter=1000).fit(data)
    df_diabetes_normalizado["clusters"] = kmeans.labels_
    sse[k] = kmeans.inertia_ 
plt.figure(figsize=(14,9))
plt.plot(list(sse.keys()), list(sse.values()))
plt.xlabel("Numero de Clusters")
plt.ylabel("SSE")
plt.show()


X = df_diabetes_normalizado
y = df_diabetes_normalizado

for n_cluster in range(2, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_cluster).fit(X)
    label = kmeans.labels_
    sil_coeff = silhouette_score(X, label, metric='euclidean')
    print("Para n_clusters={}, O Coeficiente de silueta é {}".format(n_cluster, sil_coeff))
```

I need to classificate my datas now and create a plot like image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to predict which cluster your new data belongs to, you need to use the predict method:

```
kmeans.predict(newData)
```

Here is the documentation link for the predict method:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.predict

Comment: Thank you but i need to create a column with classifications for each line based in cluster number that i faound that in my case is 2, to be able to plor a scatter.